# Оптимизация SQL запроса диапазон чисел с двух столбцов

Tags: php, sql

Всем добрый день , помогите оптимизировать выборку SQL так как иногда запрос выполняется 1,5 сек что очень много 
есть таблица ip_adress  (4 млн записей)  с ип адресами хранимая в десятичных числах к примеру 3 первых столбца

```
  ip_from       ip_to   country

 3756979712  3756984319   India

 3757184768  3757185791   China

 3758088448  3758088959   Indonesia
```

у меня есть число и мне нужно знать к какой стране он относится 
к примеру 3758088449  он попадает в диапазон Indonesia
но тут проблема чтобы найти диапазон в двух колонках мне нужно сделать запрос

Select * 
FROM `geo_city_ipv4`
WHERE `ip_from` <= 3758088449
AND `ip_to` >= 3758088449

BEETWEN нет возможности применить на две таблицы ,  как правильно сделать ? 
Заранее благодарен

Comment: индексацию делать пробовали?

Comment: есть три индекса  ip_from , ip_to, ip_from _ip_to  последний индекс я так понимаю на 2 таблицы

Comment: Не надо называть - таблицы, поля тогда уж, атрибуты. А чем вам не угодил `BEETWEN`? можно еще попробовать субд обновить, новые версии отличаются производительностью в лучшую сторону.

Comment: *BEETWEN нет возможности применить на две таблицы* Во-первых, таблица одна. Это поля - два. Во-вторых, никто не запрещает сделать `WHERE 3758088449 BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to`.

Comment: как мне найти диапазон BETWEEN   в двух столбцах? 
column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM geo_city_ipv4 
WHERE ip_to >= 3758088449
ORDER BY ip_to
LIMIT 1
```

Предполагается, что нет "ничьих" диапазонов. Если есть - придётся ввести, со страной "локалхост", "серые адреса", "апипа" и т.п., а для совсем непонятных "фиг знает".